# Jquery Function not correctly creating new markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function

I have to admit (as probably seen from my previous question) I am relatively new to Jquery. I know a little Java, but my knowledge lies mostly in CSS and HTML4/5. I am working on a project where I need to be able to create,move,and delete markers on a map. Instead of using google's api map I went ahead and made it free form so any plan could work in theory. However the problem I am having so far is a friend of mine lent me the code after he finished his project...I don't fully understand some of the stuff I am seeing and I would ask him normally but he's on a cruise (he literally left his cell phone at home too so no one would bother him).

---

On line 9 I don't understand this function grabber, is it grabbing a pages html or a function located on a page? If it does grab data from a page does that mean I would have to recreate the function? The main problem is when I click the marker button to create a new one it locks my cursor in but does not let me actually place a marker (like the event isn't being called right).

Also, the json bit at the bottom...I thought json was a language all on it's own (independent)?

---

```
function newIssue(e)
  {
     var pos = $('#plan').offset();
     var x = e.pageX - pos.left;
     var y = e.pageY - pos.top;
     var u = x/$('#plan').width();
     var v = y/$('#plan').height();

 $.get('/new/newIssue/14/' + u + '/' + v + '/' + e.data.kind + '/', function(data)
     {
        var x = eval(data);
        var num = x.number;
        Issue.push({id: num, u: u, v: v, repaired: false, kind: e.data.kind, timestamp: x.timestamp, detailed: true});
        var n = insertIntoCluster(Issue[Issue.length - 1], Cluster, 10);
        reclusterOnAddition(n);
        if (e.data.kind == 'Repairable')
           openIssue(num, true);

        $('#plan-wrapper').css('cursor', 'move');
        $('#plan').unbind('mousedown');
        $("div[id^='m']").show();
        panner.enable();
     }, 'json');
  }
```

---

```
<li><a href="javascript:prepNewIssue('Repairable')">Repairable</a></li>
```

I got flack for doing it this way, but my friends code worked fine and I am able to better understand it this way. Basically you click on the link and it makes it to where your cursor when clicked again creates a marker, however it enables the cursor but when you click again nothing is created just stuck in the loop of "creating" with no creation.

Comment: Show some more relevant code, such as how you call the `newIssue` function, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Listed the call above @Jamiec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Javascript : Java :: Carpet : Car.

Javascript is *not* Java.  As a matter of fact, from here on out, I will call it by its formal name, ECMAScript.

You've asked several questions here, but you start out by saying that you don't understand what the code on line 9 is doing.

In ECMAScript, you can pass a function as a parameter to another function.

`$.get` goes and gets data from a server.  The argument `function(data) { ... }` tells ECMAScript what to do when the data is retrieved.  Bear in mind that the other code in this block will continue executing and the function passed as a parameter will not be executed until the calling code is done. (Google: javascript event loop).

Finally, the `'json'` string after the closing brace and comma is another argument to the `$.get` function.  It tells $.get what kind of data it's dealing with so that it can be processed appropriately.

```
 $.get('/new/newIssue/14/' + u + '/' + v + '/' + e.data.kind + '/', function(data)
     {
        var x = eval(data);
        var num = x.number;
        Issue.push({id: num, u: u, v: v, repaired: false, kind: e.data.kind, timestamp: x.timestamp, detailed: true});
        var n = insertIntoCluster(Issue[Issue.length - 1], Cluster, 10);
        reclusterOnAddition(n);
        if (e.data.kind == 'Repairable')
           openIssue(num, true);

        $('#plan-wrapper').css('cursor', 'move');
        $('#plan').unbind('mousedown');
        $("div[id^='m']").show();
        panner.enable();
     }, 'json');
```

As for your question about JSON being an entirely different language, that is not correct.  JSON is an acronym for "JavaScript Object Notation".  It is a way of representing data as Javascript (ECMAScript) code.  It is strictly a subset of the ECMAScript language.

Here is an example of some JSON representing information about a car:

```
{
    Year: 2013,
    Make: "Acura",
    Model: "TL",
    IsInService: true
    Drivers: [{
        FName: "Bob",
        LName: "Smith"
    }, {
        FName: "Sue",
        LName: "Smith"
    }]
}
```

**Update:** I know that this answer is running a bit long, but I'm going to refactor this code in a way that might help you understand better what is happening:

```
function newIssue(e)
  {
     var pos = $('#plan').offset();
     var x = e.pageX - pos.left;
     var y = e.pageY - pos.top;
     var u = x/$('#plan').width();
     var v = y/$('#plan').height();

     var ajaxTarget = '/new/newIssue/14/' + u + '/' + v + '/' + e.data.kind + '/';

     var callbackFunction = function(data)
     {
        var x = eval(data);
        var num = x.number;
        Issue.push({id: num, u: u, v: v, repaired: false, kind: e.data.kind, timestamp: x.timestamp, detailed: true});
        var n = insertIntoCluster(Issue[Issue.length - 1], Cluster, 10);
        reclusterOnAddition(n);
        if (e.data.kind == 'Repairable')
           openIssue(num, true);

        $('#plan-wrapper').css('cursor', 'move');
        $('#plan').unbind('mousedown');
        $("div[id^='m']").show();
        panner.enable();
     };

     // Call $.get with three parameters,
     // ajaxTarget: tells $.get where to get data from.
     // callbackFunction: tells $.get what to do with the data.
     // 'json': tells $.get that we are getting json data.
     $.get(ajaxTarget, callbackFunction, 'json');
  }
```

Comment: Long is better for me, I don't mind learning new things and I especially don't mind more educated people teaching me these new things. I appreciate the time you put into this answer and I will be studying this message.

Comment: Is there a better way to carry out the command without using Ajax? I am not quite sure what this line of code is trying to grab from the "/new/newIssue/14/' url or whatever it is. Does that mean there is separate code on that page listed?

Comment: AJAX refers to when the Javascript code retrieves data from the server without loading a new page.  Therefore, if you need to have data loaded by Javascript *after* the page loads, then AJAX is required.

Comment: I like to refer people learning Javascript to the Dougas Crockford YUI Javascript videos: http://www.yuiblog.com/crockford/

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to understand question, I cant see a function `grabber` on line 9. Line 9 does execute jQuery's [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method which does execute an [AJAX request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

This request specifies that it expects json back, which implies the parameter passed to the callback function (`data`) contains some data in json format. (Incidentally, [`JSON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is nt an independent language - its just Javascript).